# function interface invoke in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new in kotlin, I write java always.
I try some functional code in java way by kotlin but doesn't work.

I translate these code to java and it works.

```
fun doIt(content: String, fInter: FInter) {
    fInter.doItForString(content)
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface FInter {
    fun doItForString(string: String)
}

fun main() {

    doIt("abc") {
        println(it) // why it error
    }

}
```

---

Even if `FInter` is a java interface. It doesn't work either.

---

update

### Summary

I try in some different ways, now they are work .

```
package com.linuxea.javalin

/**
 * @author linuxea
 * @date 2019/9/2 11:58
 */

@FunctionalInterface
interface StringHandler {
    fun handle(content: String): String
}

class ToUpperCaseStringHandler : StringHandler {

    override fun handle(content: String): String {
        return content.toUpperCase()
    }

}

fun go(string: String, stringHandler: StringHandler) {
    println(stringHandler.handle(string))
}


fun go(string: String, stringHandler: (String) -> String) {
    println(stringHandler(string))
}

fun main() {
    go("abc", ToUpperCaseStringHandler())

    go("dfalkdjkskf") {
        it.toLowerCase()
    }

    go("abcdefg") {
        println(it)
        it.toUpperCase()
    }

    // lambda argument should be moved out of parentheses
    go("xyz", {
        it.toUpperCase()
    })
}
```

Comment: Even if My <code>FInter</code> is a java interface, it doesn't work again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Kotlin works not so great with SAM interfaces. In the case with Java interface you can use it like this:

```
// Java
public interface FInter {
    void doItForString(String string);
}

// Kotlin
fun main() {
    doIt("abc", FInter { println(it) })
}
```

but also you can use the function type `(String) -> Unit` instead of an interface:

```
fun doIt(content: String, fInter: (String) -> Unit) {
    fInter(content)
}

fun main() {
    doIt("abc") {
        println(it)
    }
}
```